# Add/Subtract Inventory Data in MULTIPLE columns, not just ONE column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

**What should I do to change the code below (at the very bottom) so that it works for multiple column pairs, not just one column pair?**

I am tracking inventory in a sheet, something like this:

```
ColA      ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE  ColF  ColG  ColH
Category  Item  R+/-  G+/-  B+/-  Red   Green Blue
AAA        A                       1     0     0
AAA        B                       2     1     0
```

I want to be able to type numbers into ColC, ColD and ColE and then click a button to subtract those numbers from the totals in ColF, G and H, respectively.

I found a similar question with a great answer here, for ONE column pair:
[Google Sheets - How to create add and subtract buttons to track inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267669/google-sheets-how-to-create-add-and-subtract-buttons-to-track-inventory). The code got me started. I'm pretty sure I needed to update the ***getRange* stuff** from what it was (shown immediately below) to what is now listed in the whole function code further down. (I also changed some names/variables to better match my inventory needs.)

```
  var updateRange = sheet.getRange(2, 3, maxRows); // row, column, number of rows
  var totalRange = sheet.getRange(2, 4, maxRows);
```

But what do I do with the ***for* section** so that it works for all three column pairs, not just for ColC & ColF? I tried adding a "var col in updateValues" but it didn't like col (or column); besides i wasn't sure how to nest it with the var row that's already there. (I did notice that if I changed the 0 after each [row] to 1, it would do the 2nd columns. But it didn't like it when I did "var col in updateValues" and then "updateValue[0][col]".)

```
function subtractUpdateBulk() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  var updateRange = sheet.getRange(2, 3, maxRows, 3); // row, column, # of rows, # of cols
  var totalRange = sheet.getRange(2, 6, maxRows, 3);

  var updateValues = updateRange.getValues();
  var totalValues = totalRange.getValues();
  for (var row in updateValues) {
    var updateCellData = updateValues[row][0];
    var totalCellData = totalValues[row][0];

    if (updateCellData != "" && totalCellData != "") {
      totalValues[row][0] = totalCellData - updateCellData;
      updateValues[row][0] = "";
    }
  }

  updateRange.setValues(soldValues);
  totalRange.setValues(totalValues);
}
```

If you offer code alone is great. A bit of explanation to go with it would be even better, so I understand the WHY and can hopefully apply it elsewhere.

Comment: In order to understand correctly the logic you want to achieve, can you provide the samples before and after the expected script is run? I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was pretty close.

This is the substitute code to manage three columns of data movements and three columns of totals. Most of the code is self-explanatory but I'll focus on a couple of points. Its good that you're interested in the why as well as the how, and I've left some DEBUG lines that hopefully with assist.

1) I setup the spreadsheet and sheet using "standard" commands. In this case, I used `getSheetByName` to ensure that the code always would execute on the desired sheet.

2) I didn't use `getMaxRows` because this returns "the current number of rows in the sheet, regardless of content.". So if your spreadsheet has 1,000 rows but you've only got, say, 20 rows of data, `getmaxRows` will return a value of 1,000 and force you to evaluate more rows than are populated with data. Instead I used the code on lines 30 and 30 `var Avals` and `var Alast` which use a javascript command to quickly return the number of rows that have data. I chose Column A to use for this, but you could change this to some other column.

3) Rather than declare and get values for two ranges (`updateRange` and `totalRange`), I declared only one data range `totalRange` and got the values for all 6 columns. `getValues` is a fairly time costly process; by getting values for all rows and all columns, you can then pick and choose which columns you want to add together.
The command is:
`var totalRange = sheet.getRange(NumHeaderRows + 1, 3, Alast - NumHeaderRows, 6);`
The syntax (as you noted) is row, column, # of rows, # of cols.
The start row is the row following the header => (NumHeaderRows + 1).
The start column is Column C => 3.
The number of rows is the data rows less the header rows => (Alast - NumHeaderRows)
The number of columns is ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF, ColG => 6

4) `for (var row in totalValues) {`
This was a new one for me, and its so simple, so I keep it.

5) I used two arrays, just as you did. I used one array (`RowArray`) to build the values for each row, and the second array (`MasterArray`)is cumulative.
BTW, in your code `soldValues` isn't ever declared and no values are ever assigned to it.

6) The most important thing is the calculation of the adjustments on each line:
For the sake of clarity, I declared three variables `totalRed`, `totalGreen` and `totalBlue`, and showed how the totals were calculated for each value. This wasn't strictly necessary (I could have just pushed the formulas for each new totals), but they enable you to how each movement is calculated, and the column numbers used in each case.

```
function so_53505294() {

    // set up spreadsheet
    // include getsheetbyname to ensure calculations happen on the correct sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

    //set some variables
    var NumHeaderRows = 1; // this is the number of header rows - user changeable
    var totalRed = 0;
    var totalGreen = 0;
    var totalBlue = 0;

    // arrays used later in loop
    var RowArray = []; // row by row values
    var MasterArray = []; // row by row, cumulative values

    // get number of rows of data
    var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
    // Logger.log("the last row = "+Alast);// DEBUG

    // define the entire data range
    var totalRange = sheet.getRange(NumHeaderRows + 1, 3, Alast - NumHeaderRows, 6); // row, column, # of rows, # of cols
    //Logger.log("the TotalRange = "+totalRange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG

    // get the data fior the entire range
    var totalValues = totalRange.getValues();

    // loop through thr rows
    for (var row in totalValues) {

        // clear RowArray at the start of each new row
        RowArray = [];

        // calculate the new totals
        totalRed = totalValues[row][0] + totalValues[row][3];
        totalGreen = totalValues[row][1] + totalValues[row][4];
        totalBlue = totalValues[row][2] + totalValues[row][5];
        //Logger.log("row = "+row+", Movement RED  = "+totalValues[row][0]+", Old Stock RED = "+totalValues[row][3]+", New RED = "+totalRed); //DEBUG
        //Logger.log("row = "+row+", Movement GREEN  = "+totalValues[row][1]+", Old Stock GREEN = "+totalValues[row][4]+", New GREEN = "+totalGreen); //DEBUG
        //Logger.log("row = "+row+", Movement BLUE  = "+totalValues[row][2]+", Old Stock BLUE = "+totalValues[row][5]+", New BLUE = "+totalBlue); //DEBUG

        // update the RowArray for this row's values
        RowArray.push(0, 0, 0, totalRed, totalGreen, totalBlue);
        // update the MasterArray for this row's values
        MasterArray.push(RowArray);
    }

    // Update the data range with the new Master values.
    totalRange.setValues(MasterArray);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the update to the code AND the explanations! In the meantime, I added a column in between the first three columns and the last three, containing a formula. So in the code, I changed the total columns to 7 and updated the totalValues[row][#] as needed but then didn't know what to do in RowArray.push to keep the formula column intact. So I took the easy way out: moved the middle column off to the side instead and reverted the code back to 6 columns. : ) So now it works exactly as needed!

Comment: That's practical thinking! If the answer was useful to use, then you have the option to "accept" it.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that. I'm still learning how to use this site. : )